# How can I use inputs of lower frequencies to predict an output of higher frequency?

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, frequency, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I would like to use a [NARX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_autoregressive_exogenous_model) or a [LSTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory) to use different type of data at different frequencies -for instance weekly, monthly and quarterly- to predict data sampled at a higher frequency -in my case, daily data-

The problem is that, for instance using a LSTM or another Recurrent Neural Network I do not now how to 'align' the input vectors to the output vectors, for instance if the input vector has two elements, one that comes from data that exists on fridays and another that is monthly at the first friday of the month, then I have for the first friday of the month:

> Input vector:
>   [weekly_data<sub>1</sub>,monthly_data]
>   
> Output vector: [daily_data<sub>first friday</sub>]

But for the second friday of the month I have:

> Input vector:
>   [weekly_data<sub>2</sub>,**?**]
>   
> Output vector: [daily_data<sub>second friday</sub>]

And for any other day, for instance wednesday I have:

> Input vector:
>   [**?**,**?**]
>   
> Output vector: [daily_data<sub>wednesday<sub>k</sub></sub>]

The question would be, how to fill the **?** ie the missing values in the input vectors due to the different frequencies of input and output data? Or do I have to take another approach?

Comment: One related keyword is MIDAS (**mi**xed **da**ta **s**ampling; MIDAS regression or MIDAS model); perhaps you can get some useful ideas from the MIDAS literature.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have been reading about MIDAS and also found an r package [link](http://mpiktas.github.io/midasr/) by @mpiktas  but It seems from what I understood that it is useful for predicting **lower** frequencies from **higher** frecuencies and what I need is the other way round or a I am missing something?

Comment: Yeah, it probably works as you say.

Comment: Aniway, I am not very proficient in statistics, let's hope someone can confirm how to use MIDAS in this case or another method